# How to handle "Is X possible?" questions? (Does no answer mean not possible?)

Tags: discussion, bounties, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

Several of my questions can be summarized as "I was trying to do **A** but the closest I can come is **B**.  Is **A** even possible?  If so how?"

The usual response to this is a few people telling me to do **B** or something very similar to it.  I never get anything that says I can't do **A** and should do **B** just that I can do **B** which I already knew. I'll reply saying something like I'm looking for **A** not **B** and then after a matter of hours the responses stop all together.   Sometimes people will vote for the answer telling me to do **B** but I don't usually accept the answer as my question hasn't actually been answered.

I usually end up sticking with **B** but hoping someone will post something that will help me do **A** someday.  If I accept any of these "answers" then I'm not likely to get a answer about **A**.  Once I tried putting a bounty on the question which resulted in no new answers and forced me to mark the question as answered even though it wasn't.

My question is when, if ever, should I give up and accept the lack of someone saying **A** is possible as proof that it is not and how should I "answer" the question?  Should I mark one of the answers telling me to do what I'm already doing as the accepted answer?  Should I post my own answer saying that it appears that it can't be done?  Should I leave it without an accepted answer?

Comment: You should associate your accounts; that will give you 100 reputation.

Comment: Thanks!  Have you always been able to do that?  I thought I tried to a million years ago when I first created my meta account.

Answer (score 10):

Don't ask if it's possible, just ask how to do it.  Also, don't answer your own question by providing the **B** alternative right away.  Give people a chance to ponder **A** for a while first.  If someone else comes up with **B** independently, then odds are improved that it's the best way to proceed.

Comment: I guess I try to make it clear that I know B is possible and I don't want it so I don't have people tell me if I googled it I would find B.

Comment: @drs9222: There are definitely certain types of questions where you want to mention up front that you've already considered and discarded B for whatever reason (the whole "you should be using jQuery" meme springs to mind).  I think in those cases it's important to present a good reason why B isn't what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The only way that "no, that's not possible" is a valid answer is if it can be proven to be impossible.  Otherwise, it's really "that's not easy to do", or "no one has done that yet", etc.

Comment: Exactly.  That is why I currently let them hang without accepting an answer.

Comment: Yep, I do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Bill's Advice sounds good.

However, if it gets lots of views and nobody knew how to do what you really wanted, then there is a good chance someone who was trying to do the same thing found that question.  If they ever figure it out and have a stackoverflow account, they can still post the answer and you envelope icon will turn red :-)

I think the chances of that are good because if it is obscure and hard, if someone figures it out they will probably look for at least one person who cares.