# How do you answer a question whose premise can be improved?

Tags: discussion, answers

If a user asks a question that is based on bad practice or can be optimised, should/can answers suggest a solution that goes beyond the bounds of the original question?

If so, what is the best way to tell if a solution is still on-topic or if it goes too far beyond the scope of the question?

This question is related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263661/does-stack-exchange-allow-for-answers-which-question-the-validity-or-stance-of-t), but that asks specifically if those sorts of answers are valid, not to what degree that applies.

Consider this: A user has asked a question where they describe their problem. They then write their attempted solution that uses a specific method.
You see that the method they use is flawed in some way (it's overly complicated, it's not very comprehensible, it's inefficient), but as is often the case the final line of their question reads something like "How can I use this method to get what I want?", and the question title itself refers to the method originally used.

It's rarely clear whether the question is premised on the method, so what is the best way to determine this?

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Comments can/should be used to ask for clarification, so when you say you're looking for the best way to determine whether the question is premised on the method, are you looking for something other than comments? Are you looking for a way to answer the question, or for a way to determine if the question depends on the method described in it?

Comment: The latter. If you have a question that you're pretty sure assumes that the attempted method is the best (and isn't), but where the question itself is tied to the method. While an answer that strays away from the question itself may answer the OP's issue, it doesn't help future users searching for a solution to the original question. I've seen questions closed as duplicate although the answers given don't actually answer the original question, which surely can't be how SE is supposed to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It's rarely clear whether the question is premised on the method, so what is the best way to determine this?

In that case, use comments. You can simply ask whether they really have to use a certain method, whether they are aware there are other ways to do the thing that aren't complicated.

Until that is clarified, such questions should probably be closed as 'needs details or clarity', because you don't know what the answer is/should be taking into account. I would definitely recommend against answering such posts until it's clear that the time you will spend answering will be spent on answering the 'right' version/interpretation of the question.