# Box drawing characters etc. display fail in code block and in mobile browsers

Tags: feature-request, fonts

I have used the `code` block to display grids like this:

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│6th│ 5▲│4th│ 3▲│2nd│1st│0th│
╞═══╪═══╪═══╪═══╪═══╪═══╪═══╡
│   │ 1 │   │ 4 │   │   │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

as well as math writing like this: `⟨       ³ʳᵈa     ⁰ᵗʰb ⟩, (ab)₁₀ ≥ 51`.

(for a complete post please refer to https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/124830)

It looks nice in desktop browsers. My problem is that in mobile browsers of an Android phone, the box drawing characters do not display properly as monospaced fonts, and some characters fails to display at all:

[image]

I think it is related to CSS font family issue.

FYI: I've run into a similar problem before when I wrote the CSS code for a website to display this type of characters. The code that works for me is ​​this:

```
font-family: "Fira Code", Consolas, monospace, sans-serif, system-ui;
```

Edit after accepting answer:

I'm sorry if I have made a bad suggestion. I am just unfamiliar with this site. I just wanted to suggest that, instead of "either A or B", maybe "both A and B" is ok as well. I think it would be good, if both common and uncommon characters can be shown properly as monospaced fonts (or at least be shown) in code block. Examples and usage may be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character#Examples and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art.

Comment: Relevant cross-site post: [Misalignment of Unicode block characters in preformatted text blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391170/misalignment-of-unicode-block-characters-in-preformatted-text-blocks)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**[Frame challenge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263672/): don't bother, use the built-in formatting instead.**

I'm on mobile right now and one of your tables looks like this:

[image: code table using misaligned box-drawing characters]

To evangelize Stack Exchange's own [Markdown table formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/), here's the same table*:

| 6th | 5▲ | 4th | 3▲ | 2nd | 1st | 0th |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 |  | 4 |  |  |  |

On my mobile, it looks like this:

[image: table in Markdown formatting]

Markdown source:

```
| 6th | 5▲ | 4th | 3▲ | 2nd | 1st | 0th |
|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|
| | 1 | | 4 | | | |
```

Why is this better? Besides looking better, I mean. Let me list the ways!

- **Technical correctness**: The browser knows this is a table, so it generates proper HTML, with `<table>` tags and everything. In contrast, a code block table looks like... code. Computer code, or at least computer code adjacent.
- **Accessibility**: Because this is a proper table, screen readers or other assistive technologies can treat it like a table. This makes [navigating and understanding tables easier](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11371).
- **No Unicode**: Instead of having to grab the correct Unicode character for each edge, or using some generator, Markdown tables can be easily typed using a standard keyboard setup. I did so for the above one. The sole exception was the triangles, which I had to copy from yours.

**Code blocks are not meant for fancy formatting**. They're meant for code. Instead of forcing them to do nice Unicode tables, why not use the built in table formatting?

<sub>* Yes, I typed that on my phone. Yes, it is night where I am. Yes, I am theoretically on vacation. Yes, I am perfectly happy with my life choices, thank you very much.</sub>

---

On a related note, doing **fancy Unicode for math *also* has problems**. Namely, that my browser has no idea what some of these characters are.

[image: math display in a code block with unavailable characters shown as Xs]

Since you're hitting the limits of commonly available Unicode, maybe use MathJax instead? Puzzling Stack Exchange has a handy [MathJax guide for puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7421/). It won't be accessible to screen readers, but it will at least be readable to visual users without access to those special characters.

Comment: Frame challenge challenge: how do you turn the diagram in <https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/21917/15334> into a Markdown table? Or <https://stackoverflow.com/a/71867088/3840170>? Or <https://stackoverflow.com/a/68644654/3840170>? Or <https://stackoverflow.com/q/1992808/3840170>?

Comment: @user3840170 Those aren't accessible either, but not every such problem has the same solution. Most of those should probably be images with appropriate alt text. And #3/4 looks like it should really not be a diagram (or code block) at all, but plain text with some emphasis.

Comment: @bobble Thanks for your reply! I'm sorry if I ruined your vacation. I am just unfamiliar with this site. Back to the answer. You've given very good point. I just wanted to suggest that, instead of "either A or B", we may consider if "both A and B" is ok as well.

Comment: @alife 1) Writing this answer was quite relaxing, actually 2) I have little idea what your last sentence was about. My best guess is that code tables = A, Markdown tables = B? I wouldn't recommend doing both at once... you presented a specific problem with A, I suggested that B was a better solution. In some cases (see above comments) A may work better, in that B doesn't work at all. But that's irrelevant for the situation you presented, where B does work.

Answer (score 1):

Box-drawing characters are not necessarily a good fit for tabular data (more precisely: each-row-a-record tables with one row of headers), as that case is better served by native Markdown tables; but that doesn’t mean they aren’t useful in other circumstances.  Like drawing diagrams, which I happen to like using them for: [#1](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/29567/15334), [#2](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/21917/15334), [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77741904/3840170).  So the problem deserves a straight solution, not mere “I know better than you what your problem is” solution dodging.

Now that Firefox for Android has **finally** re-enabled extensions (as of version 120), you can work around this by installing [Stylus](https://add0n.com/stylus.html) and applying a custom stylesheet pointing to a web font like Source Code Pro:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/4bbbf01dcf69752d527dbad061e2977b30d0bee2/WOFF2/OTF/SourceCodePro-Regular.otf.woff2) format('woff2');
}

body {
  --ff-mono: 'Source Code Pro';
}
```

Downloading the WOFF2 font file will incur about 80 kB of traffic.  For comparison, just the HTML code for the main page of meta.stackexchange.com weighs ~246 kB, and the HTML code for this very question page I measured at ~121 kB; so if you need to count every kilobyte of your data plan, this font file should be the least of your problems.  But if you can find a way to install the font locally to your device, you can avoid spending even this little.

The same user stylesheet can be applied on a full-size computer, where you’ll presumably have less trouble installing custom fonts (so the impact of web fonts can be diminished).  You can of course substitute another font of your choosing and/or adjust [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) for `pre` elements as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I hope my work can be universal and handled easily by everyone (that is one reason I chose text instead of html), but your answer have taught me some new thing that I like to know.

Comment: @alife What do you mean "text instead of html"? **Everything you type is turned into HTML.** When you put something in code formatting, the Markdown parser will wrap it within `<code>` tags. (See the [HTML source of this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awNka.png)). When you put something in bold (wrap it with `**`), corresponding HTML is generated. When you type unformatted text, it is wrapped with`<p>` tags. Table formatting is just another kind of formatting, and using it produces HTML appropriate for a table. Which is, as I mentioned, accessible to screen readers.

Comment: I can’t say I understand that comment either.

Comment: I am sorry that I have written something confusing. It has become unrelated to my original post/intention and I prefer to end the discussion for a better sake. I just self-reflected on what I should do if I write an app that users can share content. Wish you a Happy New Year!